# when I expect to get Int but the external function return None

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
def fibonacci(t0, t1, b, n):
    t2 = t1**2 + t0
    t0 = t1
    t1 = t2
    b += 1
    if (n > b):
        fibonacci(t0, t1, b, n)
    else:
        return t2
```

... (define t0, t1, b, n)
fb = fibonacci(t0,t1,b,n)

But fb=None. Why t2 is not returned?

Comment: `if (n > b):
        return fibonacci(t0, t1, b, n)`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (n > b):
    fibonacci(t0, t1, b, n)
else:
    return t2
```

Both branches need a `return` statement. Calling a function recursively does not automatically pass the return value to the top of the call stack.

```
if (n > b):
    return fibonacci(t0, t1, b, n)
else:
    return t2
```